# VLOOKUP Dates with sum

Tags: excel, date, sum, vlookup

I am trying to use VLOOKUP to find a date, return the value and also sum all the values corresponding with that date.

```
Date    Qty.          Lookup Date:
8/12/2013   5              8/12/2013
8/12/2013   4
8/12/2013   3
8/12/2013   2
8/12/2013   1
8/20/2013   78
8/20/2013   50
8/20/2013   44
8/20/2013   12
```

It needs to grab all Qty. values corresponding with 8/12/13 and sum them. Is this possible? Am I using the wrong function?

Also, if the dates aren't in order, is this still possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [SUMIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx).

```
=SUMIF(<Your range>,<your date>,<your range to sum (qty)>)
```

This should work for you.